# Are there any other items that cast abilities under certain situations, or otherwise augment ability casting?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-console

[Jeram's Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/jerams-bracers) can be used to cast Wall of Death 3 times before triggering the cooldown.

Playing as a Barbarian, there is a set bonus to cast Earthquake at the end of casting Leap. That synergizes really well with an item such as [Lut Socks](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lut-socks).

This makes me wonder if there are other items, such as items that work for Witch Doctor abilities.

Are there any other items that cast abilities under certain situations, or otherwise augment ability casting?

Answer (score 1):

### Barbarian Items

- **[Blade of the Tribes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blade-of-the-tribes)** ***two-handed mighty weapon***: Casts Avalanche and Earthquake when casting War Cry and Threatening Shout.
- **[Dread Iron](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dread-iron)** ***mighty belt***: Casts Avalanche when casting Ground Stomp.
- **[Might of the Earth](http://www.diablowiki.net/Might_of_the_Earth)** ***set***: Casts Earthquake at the end of casting Leap.
- **[Lut Socks](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lut-socks)** ***boots***: Allows the player to cast Leap up to 3 times in 2 seconds, before requiring a cool down.

### Crusader Items

### Demon Hunter Items

### Monk Items

### Witch Doctor Items

- **[Jeram's Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/jerams-bracers)** ***bracers**: Allows the player to cast Wall of Death up to 3 times in 2 seconds, before requiring a cool down.

### Wizard Items